# OneNote "Copy to sharepoint and link" size limit

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, onenote

I have a OneNote notebook that is uploaded to a SharePoint library (SharePoint 2013 Foundation). When I try and attach a file by dragging and dropping it into OneNote, I get a popup asking if I want to copy to sharepoint and link it in OneNote:

[image]

If I choose to do that, I get this message:

[image]

The file I'm copying *is* more than 50MB (it's 52MB) - where can I increase the attachment size limit? Most of my googling has lead me to the Web Application general settings where I can see the maximum upload size is set to 250 MB so that can't be the right setting.

[image]

I was able to upload it directly to the library the notebook is in, however I do get a warning that the file was blocked (it's an executable .msi)

**Edit:** I also found these steps:

Make a backup copy of the web.config, then open it
Do a Ctrl+f to find this element

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Modify the above element to match the following

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="1024000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

and do an `iisreset` but no luck so far. Sharepoint still refuses the attachment because it's bigger than 50.0MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the file was a .msi which is not allowed by default. OneNote didn't seem to be displaying the correct error message.

**First:** I made the file size change, setting `maxRequestLength="1024000"`

**Second:** I went into SharePoint Central Admin > Security > General Security > Define blocked file types > removed .msi as a blocked extension.

The file now uploads and links correctly